# APC cache making apache consume all CPU usage

Tags: apache-2.2

Greetings,

I'm trying to install APC in order to deal with a high Apache RAM usage.

I've followed this [instructions here](http://linuxhostingsupport.net/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-apc-cache-on-a-centos-server) and, from the moment I've edited php.ini my Apache CPU usage EXPLODED.

What did I do wrong? How can I be sure APC is working fine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see anything in Apache's error log?  APC in general is going to make memory usage go up, not down.  Caching addons like APC trade memory for CPU usage, so they would only help if you are seeing high CPU usage.

Do you have enough free memory?  If this is a low-spec VPS, your installation of APC could be causing Apache to swap, which would kill your server's peformance.

Comment: It's a dedicated and my issue is with RAM usage. I've tried APC because it was recommended to me here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13944/optimize-apache-for-wp-use

Comment: Think about what APC is doing: It's saving the result of CPU heavy computations by storing them in memory.  It's always going to result in a memory increase.  Take a look at the memory usage on your machine (free -m), if it's swapping you either need to lower the amount of apache workers you are using, or decrease the APC cache size.  I would suggest you try disabling all the plugins one by one, and seeing what effect this has.  It's probably a misbehaving plugin (like you were told over on the other thread), and all the caching in the world won't fix that.